# How to determine a running process given its PID in python on Windows OS?

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp, pid, tasklist

I have a python script that launches an application, and grabs the PID, and waits until that process ID is no longer found by using :

```
result = subprocess.Popen( r'tasklist /fi "PID eq ' + str(PID) + '"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

This works fine for me, until I try to run it on XP Home which of course, doesn't have tasklist.exe

Is there another way of detecting if a process is running or not, given the PID of the process.

Simply launching the process with subprocess.Popen and waiting for it to finish is NOT an option as the process must be detached as I need to perform other tasks while the initial process is running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you might want to use psutil library in python and use psutil.pid_exists(pid) to check if process is running or not.unless you have to only use Subprocess

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would be used?

Comment: import psutil psutil.pid_exists(pid) , if pid exists it will return true else false

Comment: Does XP Home have taskmgr.exe, and if so, why does it have that but not tasklist.exe? It seems to me there's no reason to have the GUI version but not the CLI version. ...Also, can you copy over the XP version of tasklist.exe from a non-Home XP machine? Would be interesting to see if it'd work...

Comment: @user1351549 Did it solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind installing [the Python Win32 extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), you can use the Windows API to wait for the process to exit like so:

```
from win32con import SYNCHRONIZE
from win32event import WaitForSingleObject, INFINITE
from win32api import OpenProcess, CloseHandle

process_handle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, False, pid)
try:
    WaitForSingleObject(process_handle, INFINITE)
finally:
    CloseHandle(process_handle)
```

This will cause the code to block until the process exits (the `INFINITE` in the `WaitForSingleObject()` value can be changed if desired; see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

---

Alternatively, without installing an extension, you can do this with `ctypes`, especially easy as all the necessary methods are in `kernel32.dll`:

```
from ctypes import windll

SYNCHRONIZE = 0x100000L
INFINITE    = 0xFFFFFFFFL

process_handle = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 1, pid)
windll.kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(process_handle, INFINITE)
windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(process_handle)
```

Of course, in this case, the error handling code (omitted) is a bit more complex and far less Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using WMIC. I think it's available in XP Home. Here is the command:

```
wmic process get description,executablepath,processid
```

Comment: It's not available on XP Home unfortunately